Transloco is not loading translations in Angular 17
Here is a minimal reproduction: link
I am using Angular (17) with Transloco.
After following the instructions in the documentation I have attempted to translate a simple text using the structural directive inside a template
<ng-container *transloco="let t"> <h2>{{ t('greeting') }}</h2> </ng-container>
The issue is that as you can see, no text is rendered at all.
I have tried to use both relative and absolute path for the translation files, and also noticed that there is no Http call in the network tab, indicating that the translations aren't being fetched.
Full code
main.ts
import { Component, inject, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslocoHttpLoader } from './transloco-loader';
import { TranslocoService, provideTransloco } from '@jsverse/transloco';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <ng-container *transloco="let t">
      <h2>{{ t('greeting') }}</h2>
    </ng-container>
    <button (click)="onChangeToSpanish()">Change to Spanish</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  private translocoService = inject(TranslocoService);

  onChangeToSpanish() {
    this.translocoService.setActiveLang('es');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideTransloco({
      config: {
        availableLangs: ['en', 'es'],
        defaultLang: 'en',
        // Remove this option if your application doesn't support changing language in runtime.
        reRenderOnLangChange: true,
        prodMode: !isDevMode(),
      },
      loader: TranslocoHttpLoader,
    }),
  ],
});

transloco-loader.ts
import { inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Translation, TranslocoLoader } from '@jsverse/transloco';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TranslocoHttpLoader implements TranslocoLoader {
  private http = inject(HttpClient);

  getTranslation(lang: string) {
    return this.http.get<Translation>(`/assets/i18n/${lang}.json`);
  }
}

Since this should be straight through, I feel like I am missing something.

The problems with the code are follows.

Since we are using *transloco structural directive, it's required to add the import TranslocoDirective to the imports array of the standalone component.

In the angular.json file we need to reference the assets folder, so that the translations files are resolved when we look them up.


angular.json
...
"options": {
    "assets": ["src/assets"],
    ...

Full code
import { Component, inject, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslocoHttpLoader } from './transloco-loader';
import {
  TranslocoService,
  provideTransloco,
  TranslocoDirective,
} from '@jsverse/transloco';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [TranslocoDirective],
  template: `
    <ng-container *transloco="let t">
      <h2>{{ t('greeting') }}</h2>
    </ng-container>
    <button (click)="onChangeToSpanish()">Change to Spanish</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  private translocoService = inject(TranslocoService);

  onChangeToSpanish() {
    this.translocoService.setActiveLang('es');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideTransloco({
      config: {
        availableLangs: ['en', 'es'],
        defaultLang: 'en',
        // Remove this option if your application doesn't support changing language in runtime.
        reRenderOnLangChange: true,
        prodMode: !isDevMode(),
      },
      loader: TranslocoHttpLoader,
    }),
  ],
});

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks, it worked! This wasn't mentioned in the documentation, I am curious, why do I need to declare the path to the assets folder since in the loader file I specify the path to the asset files? I am new to angular, so still learning

@codrut It might be a limitation of stackblitz only, but it was required to get it to start working, do ignore it if its not needed, why the docs are lacking might be due to angular standalone components being introduced recently, this is why the docs are not fully accurate for standalone flow!

If you are in an NX monorepo the asset belongs into the project.json like this:
{ "glob": "**/*", "input": "apps/test/src/assets/i18n", "output": "/assets/i18n/" }
